# WP8: Change the Listboxitem Datatemplate on Selection Changed

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

I have a listbox in windows phone 8,

For that i want to change the datatemplate for the Selected Item.

I have done this is WPF like :

```
<Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Green" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <ListBox x:Name="lstItems" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}" />
```

But i don't know how to achieve this in Windows Phone 8 because it doesn't

support `Trigggers`

Answer (score 1):

in C# you can easily use

ListBox.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["yourkeytemplate"];

dont forget to declare your template in resource XAML

Answer (score 0):

I was trying i got success.

We can use `VisualStateManager` for this

```
<Page.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="20"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red" FontSize="20"/>
        </DataTemplate>

<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="custom">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,10" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" >
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContentTemplate">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContentTemplate">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContentTemplate">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}"/> 
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedDisabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContentTemplate">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContentTemplate">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContentTemplate">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid x:Name="InnerGrid"
                          Background="Transparent" >
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PressedBackground"
                                   Fill="{ThemeResource ListBoxItemPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                   Opacity="0" />
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                                   Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                   StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                                   StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                   Opacity="0"
                                   StrokeDashOffset=".5" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                                   Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                   StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                                   StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                   Opacity="0"
                                   StrokeDashOffset="1.5" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
<Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="lstItems" 
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource custom}"/>
</Grid>
```

Sorry it's bit long, but i thought it may help someone !! :)